# enforce that horizontal and vertical colorbar have same size as axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, contour, colorbar

I have both, a scatter plot and an additional contour plot in the foreground. For both I want to plot the corresponding colorbars beside the main plot. Unfotunately I am not able to enforce the proper size of the colorbars. I have tried

```
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax_r = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
cax_hor = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="5%", pad=0.15)
```

but wasn't able to apply this correct. My code that produces the colorbars with the undesired size is the following:

```
import matplotlib as mpl

params = {
    'figure.figsize'    : [5.0, 4.0],
    'legend.fontsize'   : 12,
    'text.usetex'       : True,
    'xtick.major.size'  : 6,
    'xtick.minor.size'  : 4,
    'ytick.major.size'  : 6,
    'ytick.minor.size'  : 4
}

mpl.rcParams.update(params)
mpl.rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import math
import scipy.interpolate
import os          
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from glob import glob 

xax = r'$\mu $'
yax = r'$\nu $'

a  = np.genfromtxt(r'data.dat', usecols = (0), unpack=True)
b   = np.genfromtxt(r'data.dat', usecols = (1), unpack=True)
r = np.genfromtxt(r'data.dat', usecols = (4), unpack=True)
p    = np.genfromtxt(r'data.dat', usecols = (5), unpack=True)

N = 100 #number of points for plotting/interpolation

a_new  = np.linspace(-22.0, 22.0, N)
b_new   = np.linspace(-22.0, 22.0, N)
r_new = scipy.interpolate.griddata( (a, b), r,\
                                         (a_new[None,:], b_new[:,None]), method='cubic')
p_new = scipy.interpolate.griddata( (a, b), p,\
                                         (a_new[None,:], b_new[:,None]), method='cubic')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
CS = plt.contour(a_new, b_new, r_new, zorder=+1)

#divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
#cax_r = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
#cax_hor = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="5%", pad=0.15)

colorbar_contour = plt.colorbar(CS, orientation='horizontal')
p_scat = ax.scatter(a, b, marker='.', s=7, linewidths=0, c=p, cmap= \
          plt.get_cmap('jet'), zorder=-1)
colorbar_scatter = plt.colorbar(p_scat, orientation='vertical')

pl.xlim([-35.0, 35.0])
pl.ylim([-35.0, 35.0])
plt.xlabel(xax)
plt.ylabel(yax)
plt.show()
```

could anyone tell me (respecting my bad python skills) how to use 'devider.append_axes()' properly, or explain another method?

Thanks in advance

Comment: While its not necessary, it's often helpful to include the image that you're currently producing and use it to describe what changes you would like.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix you are right I will add this in a sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just construct the axes explicitly, using either [`plt.axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axes) or [`fig.add_axes`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes) -- both of which accept a list/tuple of 4 parameters, `[left, bottom, width, height]` in fractions of the figure size (by default).

You can then use these axes when you construct the colorbar using the `cax` argument:

```
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([...])
cbar = plt.colobar(..., cax=cbar_ax)
```

Comment: thanks, that already helped me a little, but the colorbars created that way leave the range of the image (I have explained this and added a picture in the EDIT of my question) any ideas on this also :)?

Comment: @DonkeyKong, this is an entirely different problem -- which you should open a separate question for... and it's hard to tell what the problem is because the lower color-bar is cut-off.